# I have put together an iOS file in ipa format using Cordova PhoneGap

Tags: ios, cordova, app-store, phonegap-build

And I do have the ipa file with me, and when I log onto iTunes connect I am only given two options

xcode or application loader

and neither can be installed on Linux Mint.

Is there any other way for a Linux Mint user to upload the ipa to Apple app store?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To submit to Apple you'll need a Mac. You can either use XCode to submit the app, or download Application Loader and submit the .ipa file that way. More info can be found [here](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/how_to_submit_my_phonegap_build_app_in_app_store).

Comment: It looks like I will have to spend some fortune to submit it to iOS

Comment: Oh yes, that's for sure :-) Also, please keep in mind that Apple Developer membership costs 100 USD  per year.

Comment: By the way, another piece of advice: if you plan to buy a Macbook for Xcode development, then DO NOT buy the cheapest.... Xcode and friends are quite resource demanding. You don't have to buy the most expensive either, something in the middle will do.

Answer (score 0):

There are some services like [macincloud](http://www.macincloud.com/) that allow you to rent a mac on the cloud just the time for you to submit your app. It may be cheaper than buying a mac just for that (30$ prepaid credit for 30 hours of usage for macincloud).

But of course as aready indicated by Alexey, you'll still have to pay 100$/year to apple.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately you need a mac to build and upload your phonegap app to itunes connect.

There are some services that you can use if you do not wish to purchase a mac, such as [phonegap build](https://build.phonegap.com), which will put your app in ipa format, although you will need a developer account from apple.

If you want to publish an ipa build you can rent a vps with osx or use publish services. I built [ipaupload](https://ipaupload.com) for this and there are others out there as well.